# Cropping a .usdz file

Tags: 3d

I have a program that is creating usdz 3D models from real world objects. I would like to be able to crop those objects in 3D space to remove extraneous nearby objects or walls. Is there a good existing solution for this on Mac?

I am also able to output folders with unzipped contents including usda and obj files if that helps. I would prefer a standalone program, but could incorporate tools into a Swift Mac app.